# Can I configure IIS to display custom 404 when accessing the page by IP?

Tags: iis, ip, localhost, iis-8

I'd like to access my site only by using specific host. When user tries to access the site by IP address, I'd like to show him my custom 404 error page. I've configured the error page and I've configured only desired host in the Bindings menu but when accessing the site by the IP address, IIS shows the default 404 error page instead of my configured custom page.

Comment: Use URL Rewrite module to check incoming requests, and return a custom response when you see IP address as host header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lex Li pointed me to the right direction. To achieve said behavior one should add Request Blocking Rule in URL Rewrite module, matching Request Header to the IP address and action is redirect to 404. Such settings redirect to the custom 404 page.